# Submitting paper made on Overleaf to arXiv

Tags: overleaf, arxiv

I have made a paper on overleaf that can compile even though it has errors.  Then I  tryied to submit the Latex to arXiv but got many errors.  I have also tried to upload a PDF, but got the error: “that file is generated in latex" .

Is there any way to just submit the PDF generated by Overleaf?

Comment: Have you read the arXiv [TeX submission](https://arxiv.org/help/submit_tex) and [PDF submission](https://arxiv.org/help/submit_pdf) guides?

Comment: If you have errors you should not try to use the broken output which might or might not be a valid pdf file. After an error, Tex only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to make sensible output after an error.  Better fix this errors instead of trying to upload this file to arxiv.

Comment: arXiv is a good idea in principle but execution isn't great.  arXiv uses an outdated distribution and even then doesn't take many perfectly valid LaTeX documents.

Comment: In case, here is a working guide for submitting overleaf to arxiv: https://mateuszbuda.github.io/2018/10/20/arxiv.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, there are ways to just upload the pdf without the source, but you should not do that because your impression that Overleaf can compile your file even though you have errors is wrong.

Overleaf (and indeed TeX) **cannot compile your document properly if it has errors**, Overleaf just shows you some document which might or might not be a valid pdf file. After an error, TeX only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to produce sensible output.

You should definitely fix the errors instead of trying to distribute what you think might be an acceptable pdf. This is only in your own interests. For example people using other pdf viewer than you might not be able to open your paper - you don't want to prevent anybody from reading your paper just because they cannot open it, do you?

Never ignore error messages with the argument that the output seems to look fine - it probably does not.

Comment: arXiv doesn't take pdf files anyway.

Comment: @JPi It does with a few simple hacks.

Comment: I always thought that the PDF produced by pdfTeX after an error (*if* one is produced at all) would be a valid PDF of course the contents might be a bit off or totally garbage, but I would have thought all PDF viewers could open it.

Comment: @moewe I experienced it myself multiple times that the more fussy pdf readers like adobe reader won't show the resulting file (let's not call it a pdf) but other readers would still show something.

Comment: Oh interesting. I never experienced that, but then I usually don't go around trying to open my files with all sorts of viewers when I get an error.

Comment: @moewe I had a very memorable experience when some students of mine were supposed to have their end-of-the-course presentation in front of a full lecture hall and their presentation did not open -- it did involve some running around to get a different computer so I'll remember it for a while :)

Comment: @samcarter What's the workaround?  Tried it once with each page loaded using `\includegraphics` but that didn't work.  (Was trying to get around the fact that my valid document wouldn't compile on arXiv.)